# How to add an existing GitHub repository into PHP project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

I worked with class mates on a project to build a static website using CSS and HTML. Then we used visual studios and our work was synchronized with GitHub. Now we are asked to continue our work adding PHP files using Eclipse IDE. My question is how can I add the existing repo on eclipse and share it with my friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add it to the list of Git Repositories that Eclipse knows of, and then import the interesting part (or whole) of the working directory as a project. Check the online User Guide: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories

Answer (score -1):

### Git

**Explanation:** (Provided by google)

Git is software for tracking changes in any set of files, usually used for coordinating work among programmers collaboratively developing source code during software development. Its goals include speed, data integrity, and support for distributed, non-linear workflows.

#### How to use

Detailed instructions on how to install and setup are at

https://git-scm.com/downloads

#### Configure

You might need to restart for git to properly work.
Use `git -v` to prove git has been properly installed, and then run

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "name@email.com"
```

### Import a repository

TLDR from https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Run:

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

You can also copy the URI
[image]

#### Install updates (Newer code version)

```
git pull origin main
```

**Git fetch**

1. Updates the current local working branch (currently checked out
   branch) Updates the remote tracking branches for all other branches.
2. Updates the remote tracking branches for all other branches.

from [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-pull-explained/#:%7E:text=git%20pull%20is%20a%20Git,a%20repository%20from%20a%20remote.&text=By%20default%2C%20git%20pull%20does,branches%20for%20all%20other%20branches.)

TLDR;

```
git pull REMOTE-NAME BRANCH-NAME
```

### PHP Composer

https://getcomposer.org/

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/NAME/URI",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ]
}
```